Inverse function of a vectorial function with trigonometric functions
I have to find an expression of the inverse function of $\varphi:(-\pi,\pi)\times \mathbb{R} \to S\subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$ defined by $\varphi(u,v)=(\cos(u),\sin(u),v)$ where $S=Im(\varphi)$.
My attempt is to take $(x,y,z)\in S$, so I have:
$$\begin{cases}x=\cos(u) \\ y=\sin(u) \\ z=v\end{cases} $$
But, at this point how can I define where to map $u$?
I have to prove that $S$ is a regular surface and I need to prove that $\varphi$ is an homeomorfism. The other properties are simple to verify and I have already done so.

do you mean the inverse OF the function $\phi$?

yes, sorry for the lacks

Did you mean to write $\varphi:(-\pi,\pi]\times \mathbb{R} \to S\subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$ rather than  $\varphi:(-\pi,\pi)\times \mathbb{R} \to S\subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$ ?

No, because $\varphi$ needs to be defined on an open set in the exercise that I'm doing (regular surfaces)

It would be helpful if you were to state the original problem

I have to prove that the image of that $\varphi$ is a regular surface

And I have to discuss the invertibility to prove that it's an homeomorfism

Then in this case, I think you only need to show that the function is injective. You don't need an explicit inverse function. So you want to show that if $\cos(a)=\cos(b)$ and $\sin(a)=\sin(b)$ where a and b are in the interval $(-\pi,\pi)$ then  $a=b$. This definitely is true for the interval $(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$. because tangent is injective on that interval, but does this still hold for $(-\pi,\pi)\backslash (-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$?

I think it remains valid because if both sine and cosine coincide then the angle is uniquely determined. In a period, if we fix two angles having the same sine and same cosine, I would say they necessarily coincide
